# define function from prototype to Jquery

Tags: jquery, prototype

apologies for the newb question

I'm trying to redefine a function that works on prototype to use jquery.. The prototype function is defined using the code below. how should the function be defined using jquery?

```
if (!window.dosomething) {
window.dosomething = {};
}

dosomething = {

};
```

thanks

Comment: jquery to define a function?

Comment: jQuery is javascript, so doing it the same way does the same thing in jQuery. If what you really want is something that is chainable, as in attached to jQuery's prototype, you have to write it to work that way.

Comment: thanks for the replies.. But if I remove the prototype library I get a function undefined error.